# Bulk Insert, Invalid Object Error (table name), Excel VBA to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, bulkinsert, invalid-object-name

I am trying to bulk load from a CSV file to an SQL Server (both Excel and SQL Server are sitting on my laptop).  I am doing this via Excel VBA using the "bulk insert" statement.  I keep getting a run-time error of invalid object name for my table.

- I have tested the SQL in studio management and it works fine
- The table name is definitely correct
- I have tested using the different file formats and I get same error
- "insert into..." statement works fine from Excel VBA just not the "BULK INSERT"

```vb
connServer.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & pstrServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & pstrDBS & ";integrated security=sspi;"

strSQLQuery = "BULK INSERT tbl_q_member " & _ "FROM 'C:\test\bulk.csv' " & _ "WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', TABLOCK)"

connServer.Execute strSQLQuery
```

The runtime error is

> '-2147217865 (800440e37)
>
> Invalid object name 'tbl_q_member'

Comment: Is the query working in SSMS ?

Comment: Yes it is, that is the puzzling thing.

Comment: Try `"BULK INSERT [tbl_q_member] "`

Comment: Still the same error message unfortunately.

Comment: What happens when you try something like  `BULK INSERT  [DBNAME].[dbo].[tbl_q_member]`

Comment: Actually, I just re-tested in ssms and its stopped working now as well.  I will see if I can get it working again.

Comment: Nothing seems to be working now, I just tried writing a basic query and it no longer recognises the table.  Could my DB be corrupted?

Comment: Right click on the table in SSMS and click on  "Select Top 2000 rows" When a window opens what do you see below the `/****** Script....`?

Comment: I just re-ran an old query from Excel VBA using just the insert and it worked fine.  However, the bulk insert has also stopped working in ssms now with the same error not recognising the table name either.

Comment: This works fine in ssms - SELECT tbl_Q_Member.AAL
from tbl_Q_Member

Comment: The bulk insert is working again in SSMS but sill same error when using vba.